# Javascript variables after refresh page

Tags: javascript, variables, boolean-logic, page-refresh

I try to create my own collapsed sidebar, and I want to have the cookie saved for settings(collapsed or expanded bar). Here`s my code from to footer included file:

```js
var cookieRightSideBar;
var $postscontainer;
var $container;
var $infocontainer;
cookieRightSideBar = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)rightside_container\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
$postscontainer = document.getElementById('leftside');
$container = document.getElementById('rightside_container');
$infocontainer = document.getElementById('rightside');

function collapseRightside() {
    document.cookie = (cookieRightSideBar == 'collapsed') ? 'rightside_container=expanded' : 'rightside_container=collapsed';
    $postscontainer.style.width = ($postscontainer.style.width == '99%') ? '80%' : '99%';
    $container.style.display = ($container.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    $infocontainer.style.width = ($infocontainer.style.width == '0%') ? '19%' : '0%';
}


if (document.getElementById('leftside')) {
    var $myheight = document.getElementById ('leftside').offsetHeight - 62;
    document.getElementById('rightside').style.maxHeight = $myheight + 'px';
}

if (cookieRightSideBar == 'expanded') {
    $container.style.display = 'block';
    $infocontainer.style.width =  "19%";
    $postscontainer.style.width = "80%";
}
```

Its almost worked, except couple sadly things.
Then after refresh a page, I click to button for expand my bar, looks like function **collapseRightside** not worked correctly after first click(bar collapsed if was expanded but **not expanded if was collapsed**). This function properly work with any stages only after second click.
And one more... If I collaps bar, and expand again and then refresh page, the bar appear collapsed.
I understarnd what I have mistakes in logical things, but I can`t understand where?
Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Why cookies and not, say, localStorage?

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz
Cookie its because they already used in project what I try to change. If I use localStorage its can somehow to forced my code for right work?

Comment: @Yvo Cilon Well... i create jsfiddle, what recreate my problem
https://jsfiddle.net/L5unwnL9/

Comment: Here, this might get you a little further. Seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/L5unwnL9/3/ @user3543081

Comment: @Yvo Cilon, thanks. But your code have the same problems. Function aftrer first click not expand bar, but seems like change the cookie value. Second click - expand bar, but not change cookie value. From this moment, expand/collaps stage of bar, does not correspond to value in the cookies (they become are opposite).

Comment: The right answer is from Yvo Cilon:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33155334/3543081

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix your problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/L5unwnL9/5/

The problem was that you were checking for `$container.style.display == 'none'` while that value is null on page load. This fixed it on both container and infocontainer. 
I've also added createCookie and getCookie functions just because it was easier to use for me.

```
var cookieRightSideBar;
var $postscontainer;
var $container;
var $infocontainer;
var e = document.getElementById('onclick');
e.onclick = collapseRightside;
cookieRightSideBar = getCookie("rightside_container")
$container = document.getElementById('rightside_container');
$infocontainer = document.getElementById('rightside');

function collapseRightside() {
    cookieRightSideBar = (getCookie('rightside_container') == 'collapsed') ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed';

    createCookie("rightside_container", cookieRightSideBar);


    $container.style.display = (!$container.style.display || $container.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';

    $infocontainer.style.width = (!$infocontainer.style.width || $infocontainer.style.width == '0%') ? '19%' : '0%';
}


if (document.getElementById('leftside')) {
    var $myheight = document.getElementById('leftside').offsetHeight - 62;
    document.getElementById('rightside').style.maxHeight = $myheight + 'px';
}


if (cookieRightSideBar === 'expanded') {
    $container.style.display = 'block';
    $infocontainer.style.width = "19%";
}


function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```